# Windows vs2015 creates a cuda project, and the /Zi option is turned on by default in release mode. How to remove it?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, cuda

1. I create a cuda project through vs2015 (The code for vector_add is automatically created).

[image]
[create cuda project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDd8o.png)

2. Set release mode.
3. Open the property page, observe the compilation options, and notice that **/Zi** is set by default

[image]
[compile option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20ZFp.png)

[image]
[link option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1VgC.png)

4. The corresponding compilation options are：

```
"D:\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64" -x cu  -I"D:\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include" -I"D:\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Fdx64\Release\vc140.pdb /FS /Zi  /MD " -o x64\Release\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\paddle-ci\Desktop\test\test1\kernel.cu"
```

The size of the generated obj is **74** kb.

In the command line, remove /Zi and compile directly, the size of the generated .obj is **34** kb.

On some occasions, we eagerly hope that the obj size becomes smaller, and we hope to find a way to remove /Zi.

Environment:

win10 + vs2015 enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the file, and remove /Zi

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.0.props